# Failure to find x11 on nana cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, x11, nana

I am loading up nana source in CLion and cmake gives me the an error saying x11 is set to NOTFOUND

I have tried installing x11 dev libs on ubuntu but it has not helped :/

**EDIT**: I have fixed the issue above by installing (2nd Code block)

```
sudo apt install libxft-dev
```

however now I am seeing the following error (1st Code Block)

**CODE BLOCK 1**

```
fatal error: X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/Xcursor/Xcursor.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**CODE BLCOK 2**

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
/home/jirubizu/Downloads/nana_hotfix/X11_Xft_INCLUDE_PATH
   used as include directory in directory /home/jirubizu/Downloads/nana_hotfix
X11_Xft_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "nana" in directory /home/jirubizu/Downloads/nana_hotfix
```

expected to compile but for some reason its not

Comment: There are many X11 packages. libxft-dev seems an odd choice. It os a small part of X11 and may or may not bring in X11 libraries you need. Perhaps try installing libxcursor-dev and see what happens.

Comment: Forgot to reply but that has solved the issue thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

Try it before the load:

```
sudo apt install libxcursor-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install libxcursor-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxi-dev
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

here are many X11 packages. libxft-dev seems an odd choice. It os a small part of X11 and may or may not bring in X11 libraries you need. Perhaps try installing libxcursor-dev and see what happens.

from  n. 'pronouns' m
It works for me